# Inheritance in C++ , recall base function and function don't change value

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

In library TOADO.h

```
  #ifndef _TOADO_H 
  #define _TOADO_H

  class TOADO
  {
   public:
     TOADO();
     void SoDiem(int soluong);
     void addToaDo(POINT *toado);
     void setWidth(int width);
  public:
     int SoLuong;
     int Width;
     POINT* ToaDo;
 };
 #endif
```

In library FIGURE.h

```
   #include "TOADO.h"
   #ifndef _FIGURE_H
   #define _FIGURE_H

   class FIGURE:public TOADO
   {
   public :
     FIGURE();
     virtual void Draw(Graphics &graphics);
   };

  #endif
```

IN LINE.h

```
    #include "FIGURE.h"
    #ifndef _LINE_H
    #define _LINE_H

    class LINE:public FIGURE
    {
    public:
      LINE(const Color &clr,POINT* line );
      void Draw(Graphics &graphics);
    private:
      TOADO Line;
      Color color;
    }; 
    #endif
```

---

```
    int main()
    {
      LINE A(color, point); // char color , point is array point 
      A.setWidth(2);// function setWidth() in class TOADO
    }
```

why i recall base function A.setWidth(2) but function A.Width() still return Width = 1, it don't change Width = 2; 
everyone can explain for me and instruct for me how to fix it .
thanks.
so sorry, my english very bad, i don't can't describe to everyone understand
The problem is function setWidth().
it's my code
https://www.mediafire.com/?28dzv62x1kvxci2

Comment: Please work on improving the clarity of your question and on making sure it is tagged correctly.

Comment: Where's the code that actually does the setting?

Comment: do you want to me show file.cpp ?

Comment: How do you know its still 1?

Comment: Please provide a smaller fully contained example. It seems there is more code where the problem can exist.

Comment: We need to see the implementation of the classes, specifically `TOADO`.